# Mysqli result foreach resultset converted to array

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

I know this is basic question but due to lack of knowledge, I want to know how mysqli_result converted to array and result was retrieved.

Here is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `slider` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

INSERT INTO `slider` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Slider 1'),
(2, 'Slider 2'),
(3, 'Slider 3'),
(4, 'Slider 4'),
(5, 'Slider 5'),
(6, 'Slider 6'),
(7, 'Slider 7'),
(8, 'Slider 8');
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db',port);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM slider ORDER BY id";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); //This is mysqli_result Object

    foreach($result as $row) { //Here is the magic how it is converted and row is retrieved
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($row);
        printf ("<br>%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["title"]);
    }   

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //Normal way
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($row);
        printf ("<br>%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["title"]);
    }

    $result->free();
}
```

When we traverse through while, we do have to retrieve result using fetch_* methods but when I traverse through foreach, how result is retrieved? How implicitly, foreach loop is calling fetch_*?

Comment: It's a class that implements the `Traversable` interface, so using `foreach()` automatically fetches.

Comment: Interesting to know, I will go through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not that basic actually, as this behavior is rather new, and indeed it employs some magic.

As *you can read on the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)*, mysqli_result object supports [`Traversable` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), so *it can be iterated over*. And when iterated, it is calling `fetch()` internally.

So it is not converted but rather disguised as array.

Comment: Another explanation in documentation (foreach is equivalent of calling fetch_assoc) : https://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#mysqli-result.example.iterator

Answer (score 0):

This is the PHP class I am using [RTmysqli](https://github.com/rogertiongdev/RTlib/blob/master/RTphp/src/RTmysqli.php).

Usage:

```
$RTmysqli= new RTlib\RTphp\RTmysqli();
$RTmysqli->config(DB_HOST, DB_UNAME, DB_PWORD, DB_NAME);

$result = $RTmysqli->query("SELECT * FROM slider ORDER BY id");

if (!empty($result)) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
         print "<br>" . $row["id"] . "(" . $row["title"] . ")\n";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. :)